# Respostas do tipo 'Tente fazer isso..." podem ser consideradas respostas?

Tags: debate, respostas

Já vi várias respostas que começam com "Tente fazer isso...", "Tente fazer aquilo...", como essa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/42967/14674, porém algumas são bem completas e que até dão a resposta certa.

Mas ainda assim fico na dúvida se realmente é uma resposta, por começar com "tente....", pois passa a ideia de que o autor não tem convicção se realmente essa resposta é válida. Eu, particularmente, sempre respondo os "tente fazer aquilo..." como comentários e se o autor da pergunta confirmar que deu certo, posto como resposta, mas sem o "tente...".

Respostas desse tipo podem ser consideradas respostas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Reflexão

Uma resposta deve transmitir uma boa dose de confiança, não só denota que percebemos do assunto ao qual estamos a responder como também ajuda a melhorar a qualidade das respostas vizinhas e ajuda a promover o voto.

Uma resposta que começa por "tente fazer X..." não inspira confiança nenhuma, inspira a tentativa:

[image: Trial and Error]

<sup>[(c) http://bobchoat.com](http://bobchoat.com/2013/10/21/trial-and-error-plus-persistence-may-lead-to-success/)</sup>

É discutível que quem respondeu poderá está sem possibilidade de testar a sua solução, e optou por não afirmar a sua resposta, deixando-a num limbo entre a certeza e a probabilidade de estar correto. Mas contra isto rapidamente argumentamos que os comentários são o melhor local para deixar este tipo de sugestões.

Já em respostas bem elaboradas que começam por "tente fazer X...", não vejo como justificar a incerteza transmitida nas primeiras palavras da resposta.

### Resposta

Qualquer conteúdo, comece ele por que palavras sejam, se está na área das respostas e está a indicar o que poderá vir a ser uma solução para o problema, é de facto uma resposta.

Mas uma resposta não é uma linha de texto ou um link como todos já sabemos, pelo que é de esperar uma atualização à mesma num futuro próximo.

Caso tal atualização não se verifique, e caso uma resposta esteja aceite e a começar por "tente fazer X...", com o intuito de contribuir para a saúde da reputação do site, é a minha recomendação que seja deixado um comentário ao autor da resposta para que o mesmo a atualize e afirme o seu conteúdo.

### Caso salientado

Para o caso indicado na tua pergunta, a resposta está aceite, pelo que efetivamente salientou a origem do problema e foi a solução para o mesmo.

O autor da resposta, dado já ter estado no site após a aceitação da resposta, já deveria ter alterado a mesma para a afirmar.

Mesmo tratando-se de um caso onde a origem do problema não é clara, a resposta deveria afirmar aquela solução, outras respostas afirmariam outras soluções, uma delas ia estar correta para o OP, e outras corretas para futuros leitores... Não vejo grande necessidade de expressar incertezas quando estamos a apontar uma solução, salvo o em cima enunciado que para o efeito deve ser expresso nos comentários da pergunta, podendo ou não vir a originar uma resposta.

Answer (score 4):

### A origem

Apesar de parecer algo como *falta de convicção*, na verdade se trata de algo muito comum em outras comunidades do StackExchange (como o StackOverflow), o uso do "comentário" ["What have you tried?"](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/). De certa forma se tornaram respostas rápidas com o intuito forçar os OPs (tanto no SO, quanto em qualquer sistema de fórum) a formularem questões e ou testarem as possibilidades antes de "perguntar". O "Try this", seria uma maneira mais amigavel do "What have you tried?".

### StackOverflow em Português

Muitos usuários do SO em português que demonstram ter mais experiência com Q&A acabaram por começar em outras Comunidades do StackExchange antes de virem para cá e por este motivo acabaram por trazer termos como o "Try this..." ou "What have you tried?"

A questão não é a diferença entre as comunidades, a questão é que muitos como eu chegaram "caindo" de outras comunidades e acabaram por trazer para cá estes termos por comodidade e usando de maneira errada, não de propósito, mas sim por que lá isto é algo cultural (apesar que mesmo cultural isto ocasionou discordância/debates/"trocar ideias" entre alguns nos metas eg. [Is “try this” bad practice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice)).

### Qual o objetivo do "TRY" nas demais comunidades

O objetivo é fazer o OP aprender a ser menos dependente, ou até mesmo incentivar o OP a colaborar com as pesquisas e testes feitos por ele mesmo. Note, só por que este é o objetivo não quer dizer que funcione.

### Usar ou não usar no StackOverflow em Português

Vendo que muitas coisas no stackoverflow em português são diferentes das demais comunidades StackExchange, até mesmo as ferramentas de "flags" e como as regras funcionam aqui. Isto me faz pensar que só "testando" (vocês já tentaram usar "tente isto"?) conseguiriamos saber se o resultado pode ser positivo ou não.

Ao meu ponto de vista (eu nem sei se posso colocar pontos de vista em uma resposta), muitas coisas aqui se diferenciaram do StackOverflow original (o que me causou uma certa frustração) e já que aqui "estamos" fazendo a nossa maneira então realmente não devemos pegar o "carro andando" e evitar o uso de coisas que não sabemos o seu significado. Outro motivo para evitar o "tente..." ou "o que você já tentou?" é por que não existe uma referencia do link http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/ em português para orientar os OPs.

Answer (score 1):

Depende da pergunta. O AP pode está com um determinado problema específico que quem for responder pode não conseguir reproduzir o problema nas mesmas circunstâncias. Contudo, quem for responder pode ter uma pista do problema e da solução, mas não tem como validar. Nesse caso, é totalmente cabível colocar o "tente isso". Quem fez a pergunta irá validar se aquilo realmente funciona para o seu caso.

Um determinado trecho do código pode funcionar para quem respondeu. Mas pode não funcionar no ambiente de quem fez a pergunta porque o contexto é diferente. Acho que fica muito pior responder a pergunta dando certeza e não resolver o problema do perguntador.

Além disso, o site orienta que não é necessário responder a pergunta somente quando tiver a resposta 100% resolvida. Se alguém tiver uma solução parcial do problema, alguma orientação ou resultados de pesquisas feitas, isso pode ser postado como resposta. Porque isso vai ajudar na resolução do problema. Tanto o autor da pergunta pode conseguir resolver com base no que foi compartilhado, quanto qualquer outra pessoa.

Comment: Foi praticamente o que eu disse em: O objetivo é fazer o OP aprender a ser menos dependente, ou até mesmo incentivar o OP a colaborar com as pesquisas e testes feitos por ele mesmo. Note, só por que este é o objetivo não quer dizer que funcione. :)